# How many solutions in this Statue Park (Loop)?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Rules of Statue Park (Loop), from [GM Puzzles](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2018/07/statue-park-loop-by-serkan-yurekli/)

> Place each of the [twelve pentominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) into the grid once, with rotations and reflections allowed. No two pentominoes can overlap or be orthogonally adjacent, and all cells not occupied by the pentominoes must be traversed by a single, closed loop (connecting cells horizontally or vertically). The black circles indicate some cells that must be covered by pentominoes, white circles indicate spaces that may not be contained in pentominoes and must be part of the loop.

[image: blank 14x14 grid]

The puzzle intentionally has no black or white circles; it is a blank 14x14 grid. Does this puzzle have no solutions, one solution (up to rotation/reflection), or multiple solutions - and if so, how many?

P.S. this puzzle is meant for those who haven't done this genre before, so if experienced solvers could hold off posting answers that would be nice :)

Comment: The puzzle as given has no solution but the original puzzle (based on the link you provided to GM Puzzles) uses a different grid and most certainly [has a solution](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/images/puzzles/180720-StatueParkLoop-Utopic-soln.pdf).

Comment: @EngineerToast I'm not basing this off any other "original puzzle" - the link was simply proper attribution for the ruleset, because I was taking verbatim rules from the site. I guess you could say I was basing this off the genre in general.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Zero.  If I understand correctly, the U pentomino leaves a hole that can't be filled by another pentomino (because they can't be adjacent) or be part of the loop (because it's only adjacent to at most one other empty square).